# Native plugin android use on ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor, ionic5

I created a native plugin on android and I try to use on ionic. So on ionic I did :

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { CustomNativePlugin } = Plugins;

export class EmailComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.initStorage();
    }

    initStorage() {
        this.initForm();
        CustomNativePlugin.customCall({ message: 'CUSTOM MESSAGE' });
        CustomNativePlugin.customFunction();
    }
```

But I get he error : `Rollbar: Error: "Uncaught (in promise): CustomNativePlugin does not have web implementation."`
}

Answer (score 0):

In `MainActivity.java` you have to add `add(CustomNativePlugin.class);` inside the `init`

Comment: I added, the same

Comment: So, when you say "I try to use on ionic", you mean run it as web?

Comment: I try on real device by : `ionic cordova run android`. Have you an idea @jcesarmobile ?